# Determine how many different arrays are possible

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

Suppose we have a boolean array of length X. The only rule is, TRUE must not occur twice in adjacent places. Especially the array with only false values is allowed. E.g. this is forbidden: [1,1,0,0,0] and these is allowed:  [1,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0], [1,0,1,0,1] etc.  How can I use dynamic programming to determine how many different valid arrays of length X there are?

Comment: So to clarify: you mean that a `1` is disallowed from occurring in two consecutive elements?

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: @jamesdlin exactly

Answer (score 3):

Let *T*<sub>*i*</sub> be the number of arrays of length *i* that meet your criterion and end in `1`, and let *F*<sub>*i*</sub> be the number of arrays of length *i* that meet your criterion and do *not* end in `1`.

Then:

- *T*<sub>0</sub> = 0
- *F*<sub>0</sub> = 1
- *T*<sub>*i*+1</sub> = *F*<sub>*i*</sub>. (Each array of length *i*+1 that meets your criterion and ends in `1` consists of an array of length *i* that meets your criterion and does *not* end in `1`, plus an extra `1` at the end.)
- *F*<sub>*i*+1</sub> = *F*<sub>*i*</sub> + *T*<sub>*i*</sub>. (Each array of length *i*+1 that meets your criterion and does *not* end in `1` consists of an array of length *i* that meets your criterion, plus an extra `0` at the end.)
- You want *F*<sub>*X*</sub> + *T*<sub>*X*</sub>.

So you can just write a loop that calculates *F*<sub>*i*</sub> and *T*<sub>*i*</sub> for each *i* from 0 to *X*, and then return *F*<sub>*X*</sub> + *T*<sub>*X*</sub>.

(This isn't even dynamic programming, per se, because you don't need to store partial values; *F*<sub>*i*+1</sub> and *T*<sub>*i*+1</sub> depend only on *F*<sub>*i*</sub> and *T*<sub>*i*</sub>. So this is *O*(*X*) time and *O*(1) space.)

Comment: Won't T0 = 1 as well, as there are no consecutive 1's in it?

Comment: @saketk21: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. (What does your pronoun "it" refer to?)

Comment: What I was confused about is the base case. Why T0 = 0 and F0 = 1? As they both are of length 0, then they both should be 0. If you consider length 1 as the base case, then both of them should be 1, as the possible arrays are 0 and 1, i.e. T1 = 1 and F1 = 1.

Comment: @saketk21: Are you asking why the empty array `[]` doesn't end in `1`? Or are you asking why I chose to define *Tᵢ* as only counting arrays that do end in `1`?

Comment: Your latest comment helped me figure it out. I misinterpreted F as the number of arrays with length i ending in 0, rather than not ending in 1, which means an empty array is also counted in F.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can calculate the number without using DP. Since you know the total number of arrays for length N, that is `2^N'.

Now you need to deduct those `bad` arrays that do not qualify if they have adjacent `1`'s.  For an array of length N, there are these cases

```
1. the array has no 1's, only one case, and it is a valid array
2. the array has one 1's, all cases are valid
3. the array has two 1's, there are N - 1 cases which are not valid
4. the array has three 1's, there are (N-1) * (N-2) / 2 cases which are not valid
```

...

Comment: This won't work. For e.g. in case of array of length 5, 2 consecutive 1's which you consider are 11xxx, x11xx, xx11x and xxx11. However, x can still take value 0 or 1 (apart from the cases you handle in higher number of consecutive 1's).

Comment: I think it works. for example, N = 5. case 1 and 2 are all valid. case 3 will have 4 invalid cases. case 4 will have 4 * 3 / 2 = 6 invalid cases. case 5 4 * C(4,2) / 3! = 8 invalid cases. case 6 will have 1 invalid cases. so it is 2^5 - (1 + 4 + 6 + 8) = 13

Answer (score 0):

The dp solution would have two state parameters. One is the position of the array and the other is the previous position’s value. If the previous position’s value is 1 then you can only choose 0. If the previous position’s value is 0 then you can choose either 1 or 0. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need dynamic programming.
For array length X the number of valid arrays is Fib(X+1), where Fib is the array of fibonacci numbers.

X=1: valid arrays: 2

X=2: valid arrays: 3

X=3: valid arrays: 5

X=4: valid arrays: 8

and so on...

Demonstration:

Let's assume we are looking for the arrays for X and we know the number of valid arrays for X-1. We can freely add a zero to the end of each of these X-1 length arrays, so that's F(X-1) so far. We can also add a '1' to the end of each X-1 arrays which ends with 0. But how many of those arrays are? Well, it's exactly F(X-2) because we could generate the zero ending X-1 length arrays exactly the same way: by adding a zero at the end of each X-2 length arrays. So F(X) = F(X-1) + F(X-2) 
And that's exactly the definition of the Fibonacci array.

All we have to do is manually calculate the first two element to determinate if it's exactly the Fibonacci array or is it shifted.

You can even find a formula to calculate the Nth element of the fibonacci array, so it can be solved in O(1).

Comment: One must assume it is important to the OP to actually know how you came up with the answer rather than just know the answer.

Comment: If you mean Binet's Formula for Nth fibonacci number, then it is only an approximation and not the correct result. Nth fibonacci number can be computed at best in O(log n)